# Is it possible to use quotation marks for FindFirstFile() function?

Tags: c++, winapi

I try to return a specific .xls file with FindFirstFile(). Howerver it also returns .xlsx, due to naming convention. It is possible to use "*.xls" in the file explorer to return only .xls files. Does this work for the functi

Comment: Please post your code (in the form of a [MCVE]). `*.xls` should only match `.xls` files.

Comment: No.  This is a side-effect of the legacy support for 8.3 MS-Dos file names.  Turning, say, longfilename.xlsx into LONGFI~1.XLS and that matches a "*.xls" wildcard.   Completely pointless these days but still very commonly turned on for a file system.  So you do have to post-filter.

Comment: [Raymond Chen explains why](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050720-16/?p=34883). Not suprisingly, even in today's Windows 10 world, the reason dates back to literally Windows 1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Hans Passant said you got bitten by the legacy support for [8.3 MSDOS names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename).

Your `LovelyTable.xlsx` also has a secondary name, something like `LOVELY~1.XLS` and this second name is what `FindFirstFile()/FindNextFile()` gives you. The only robust way to avoid such results is to recheck what is returned back to you.

If you don't want to change the application you can also remove short names from the volume and also disable their generation. You can check the [fsutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil) command (its `8dot3name` sub-command) for that but beware that this might break some software even nowadays. (For example software believing it is installed under `C:\PROGRA~2\`)

---

I thought that  [`FindFirstFileEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfileexw) can filter-out the 8.3 names:

```
FindFirstFileEx(searchPattern, FindExInfoBasic, ...)
```

but it cannot. Thanks to @RbMm for clearing this out. `FindExInfoBasic` only avoids filling in the `WIN32_FIND_DATA`'s `cAlternateFileName` field. You still receive files discovered by their short names.

Comment: unfortunately `FindFirstFileEx` with *FindExInfoBasic* and even `NtQueryDirectoryFile` not help here. the same result. sure you not test this

Comment: As the documentatio states, "The search includes the long and short file names". `FindExInfoBasic` ignores the short names **in the returned results**.

Comment: @MSalters - yes, short name of file not queried with *FindExInfoBasic*, but this not changed that anyway *.xlsx* will be returned

Comment: @RbMm thanks for your note. Better late than never, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of support for short 8.3 filenames. Your .xlsx file is given a short name with .xls extension. And it is the short file name that is matching.

Whilst you can turn off support for short filenames of drives that you control, that option is not practical for machines that you don't control. So realistically you will have to apply your own filtering.